# Laravel - Как правильно составить migrate файл

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Как правильно составить таблицу для миграции в Laravel ?
Необходимые поля :

```
Задача
Время начала проекта
Время начала проектирования
Время конца проектирования
Время начала снабжения
Время конца снабжения
Время начала производства
Время конца производства
Время конца проекта
```

На данный момент migrate файл выглядит так :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->strong('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('zadacha');
            $table->date('date_s');
            $table->date('date_proekt_s');
            $table->date('date_proekt_e');
            $table->date('date_snab_s');
            $table->date('date_snab_e');
            $table->date('date_proizvod_s');
            $table->date('date_proizvod_e');
            $table->date('date_e');
        });
    }
```

Так правильно или же возможно как то по другому ?

Comment: strong => string. также сделать nullable конец интервала - ведь заранее он не исзвестен.

Comment: Спасибо. 
появилось много полей ,но вот когда я создаю какой то объект в поле , в нем надо ввести дату, (2020-05-06) как мне её переделать на дату в виде DD.MM.YYYY ??

Comment: дату переделываете уже тогда, когда получаете данные

Comment: Дату можно форматировать при выводе через `->format("d.m.Y")`. Наоборот, если пишите в базу - нужно превращать в формат базы.